# Actionscript 3.0: Changing the color of a complex animation

Tags: actionscript

I have a pretty complex animation of a fireball. I'm using it as an attack for an enemy in a game. I want to be able to simply switch all the colors in the fireball and that's it, just so when a different enemy fires the fireball they are different colors. Editing each individual frame is sort of out of the picture. I'm really struggling with a few things.

1) Whenever I duplicate symbol to start editing, whatever edits I make on that symbol automatically change the original symbol! AHHHH!

2) Changing the color for the fireball is too complex to go through frame by frame. Is there some way I can just invert all the colors or change the hue on all frames or something? Right now when I make a new movieclip of the original fireball, it is a complex mass of objects (becoming a "mixed"). This doesn't allow me to change any color settings, just the width and positioning. I would have to break apart each mixed object, change ALL the different objects, and then do that for every frame! Not happening!

3) I tried putting a sheet of a certain color on the top layer and then putting the alpha pretty low, but unfortunately it just doesn't look good. The flames on the end are always changing position, etc, so a sheet just doesn't do the fireball justice.

Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColorMatrices!!!

```
var colorMatrix: Array = new Array(
  [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], //red is now the old blue
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], //Green component stays the same
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], //I channel the old red to blue
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]);
var colorFilter: ColorMatrixFilter(colorMatrix);
yourFireBall.filters = [colorFilter];
```

I wrote in in browser but this should do the job.